# No responsive in HTML5

Tags: css, responsive-design

i put online my website but if i watch it from smartphone or small device every elements cant view in a responsive way! this fact never happened to me. Why?
In staging mode i cant view this website in a responsive mode, than i suppose this is not a js problem but a css error

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

a {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

p {
 color: blue;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.white-contact {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

a:hover {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
 position: absolute;
    z-index: 998 !important;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    line-height: 75vh;
    font-size: 13em;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Condiment', cursive;
}

h2 {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: blue;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

h2.last {
 color: blue !important;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
    color: blue;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

ul.do {
 padding-left: 0px;
}

h3 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color: blue;
}

h3.top-left {
 position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 49%;
    z-index: 999;
}

h3.top-right {
  position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 49%;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

h3.bottom-left {
 position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-left: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

h3.bottom-right {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 30px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 49%;
    right: 0px;
}

.top {

}

.bottom {

}

a.social {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

a.social:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: yellow;
}

canvas#canv {
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
}

.mekis-img {
  width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

section{
 margin-top: 50px;
}

section.top {
 height: 100vh;
 margin-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

section.second {
 height: 100vh;
/*    background-image: url('http://i.giphy.com/3oEdvcNIvJXteYUEXm.gif');*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;
}

section.third {
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: url('http://i.giphy.com/Dc5JEeUuPosN2.gif');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

section.last {
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: url('http://static2.blog.corriereobjects.it/seigradi/wp-content/blogs.dir/70/files/2013/02/div1.gif');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.twitter {
     text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    /* line-height: 50vh; */
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
}

img.gif-second {
     position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: -40%;
    z-index: -1;

}

.container {
 width: 90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

 

<!-- CSS -->

 <title>Mekis | Official Website</title>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Mekis Official Website | Producer , Dj Brescia, Italy | Electro, Reggae, Dub, Drum and Bass, Big Beat | Electro vs Rock with Joao at Lio Bar, Road to Zion Electro Dub, Jungle Massive," />
  <meta name="keywords" content="brescia dj, mekisdj, mekis, unnu can wid mi, drop 39, djset, electro, rock, dub, reggae, alternative, producer, electro vs rock, road to zion, sound design" />
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
  

  <link rel='stylesheet' id='default-style-css'  href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='viewport.js'></script>

  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Condiment' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- FONTS -->


 

  
  
 </head>

  <body>
   <section class="top">
   <canvas id='canv'>
   </canvas>
   <div class="top">
   <h3 class="top-left">Mekis / msdvc</h3>
   <h3 class="top-right">Official Web</h3>
   </div>
   <audio loop autoplay>
     <source src="http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/vehicle/vehicle005.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   <div class="mekis-img">
   <img src="img/mekis.png" alt="mekis">
   </div>
   <div="bottom">
   <h3 class="bottom-left"><a class="social" href="https://www.facebook.com/mekisdj/" target="blank">Facebook</a></h3>
   <h3 class="bottom-right"><a class="social" href="https://instagram.com/mekisdj/" target="blank">Instagram</a></h3>
   </div>
   </section>


   <section class="second">
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Ciao! My name is Mekis.<br/>Everyday i do some works</h2>
    <h3>What i do?</h3>
    <ul class="do">
     <li>President at <a href="http://www.cockroachintproduction.com" target="blank">Cockroach Int. Production</a></li>
     <li>Music Production</li>
     <li>Dj and Producer</li>
     <li>Sound Designer</li>
     <li>Professor for <a href="http://www.laba.edu/home/index.asp" target="blank">Laba</a> for Sound Design and Computer Graphic</li>
     <li>Web at <a href="http://www.adoratorio.com" target="blank">Adoratorio Creative Collective</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>-</p>
    <h3>What i love</h3>
    <ul class="do">
     <li>Music and Sound FX</li>
     <li>Reggae</li>
     <li>Pizza with Salami</li>
     <li>Friday Night</li>
    </ul>
    <p>-</p>
    <h3>What i hate</h3>
    <ul class="do">
     <li>Conventional Design and Music Production</li>
     <li>Mostarda</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- <img class="gif-second" src="img/mekis.png"> -->
    </div>
   </section>

   <section class="third">
    <!-- <div class="container">
    <h2>I love Twitter</h2>
    <div class="twitter">
     <p class="twitter">tweet with me. hashtag <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23msdvc&src=typd" target="blank">#mekisdj</a> (for music) or <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23mekisdj&src=typd" target="blank">#msdvc</a> (for web)</p>
    </div>
   </div> -->
   </section>

   <section class="last">
    <div class="container">
     <h2 class="last">Ok. Say hello!</h2>
     <div class="white-contact">
      <h3>Send me email for booking</h3>
      <p>Yes. I love Gmail<br/>
       massimo.devicienti[at]gmail.com<p>
     </div>

     <div class="white-contact">
      <h3>Press Kit</h3>
      <p>Do you want more info about my projects?<br/>
       click and download my press kit<p><br/>
       <small>in coming</small>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>

   <!--
   Variation of Screwed:
   http://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/xwBYvN
   !-->
  </body>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
  <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='preloader.js'></script>-->
  

</html>
```

link for website 
[enter link description here](http://www.mekis.it)

Comment: There's no magic with responsive design, you need to do that using a framework such as Bootstrap, Framework 7 or something of the likes, or do it yourself using media queries.

Comment: Start by adding the Viewport META TAG as mentioned in the answers and add Media Queries for specific devices. This should get you on the right track https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot for responsive view as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is mentioning values in px. These fixed values wouldn't change on resolution change. whereas values like em and % would change on resolution change. Also, we have responsive frameworks to do the task for us. We need to make use of media queries.

Also we need to add the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```